# ERROR: function csvread(unknown) does not exist flyway migrate

Tags: sql, csv, import, flyway, dbmigrate

I try to use flywayDB opensource - migrate function and try to create table from CSV file but I get ERROR :

```
Migration V1__Add_new_tables.sql failed
---------------------------------------
SQL State  : 42883
Error Code : 0
Message    : ERROR: function csvread(unknown) does not exist
  Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Position: 48
Location   : /Users/maayanezra/Downloads/flyway-5.1.4/sql/V1__Add_new_tables.sql (/Users/maayanezra/Downloads/flyway-5.1.4/sql/V1__Add_new_tables.sql)
Line       : 64
Statement  : CREATE TABLE public.mutations AS SELECT * FROM CSVREAD('mutation.csv')
```

when I try to upload this :

```
CREATE TABLE public.mutations
(
    id integer,
    gene_id integer,
    name text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    ...
) as select * from CSVREAD ('mutation.csv');
```

Comment: use [code block](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to display your code and quote for error message.

Comment: the ERROR :Migration V1__Add_new_tables.sql failed
---------------------------------------
SQL State  : 42883
Error Code : 0
Message    : ERROR: function csvread(unknown) does not exist
  Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Position: 48
Location   : /Users/maayanezra/Downloads/flyway-5.1.4/sql/V1__Add_new_tables.sql (/Users/maayanezra/Downloads/flyway-5.1.4/sql/V1__Add_new_tables.sql)
Line       : 64
Statement  : CREATE TABLE public.mutations AS SELECT * FROM CSVREAD('mutation.csv')

Comment: what I try to upload : CREATE TABLE public.mutations
(
    id integer,
    gene_id integer,
    .....
) as select * from CSVREAD ('mutation.csv');